# How can we know there is hole in a file in C?

Tags: c, linux, file

from the man page :

> lseek() allows the file offset to be set beyond the end of the file (but this does not change the size of the file).  If data is later written at
> this point, subsequent reads of the data in the gap (a "hole") return null bytes ('\0') until data is actually written into the gap.

we read null bytes in the gap, but what if the data in file itself is '\0' ？ how can i distinguish the null bytes is gap or '\0' data in file？

Comment: You can't tell by reading the data. Instead keep track of any holes that you add into the file yourself. Get the current file size before calling `lseek` and use that to track the position and size of any hole that will be created by the `lseek`.

Comment: @kaylum There are some scenes we deal with hole file that not created by ourselves, like copy a hole file without copying hole data to new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"hole" is maybe a misnomer - there's really no literal hole in the file. Let's a assume a "hole" to be an area in a sparse file for which storage has not yet been allocated. There is no standard way (yet) to detect such un-allocated storage in files. For all intents and purposes, the "holes" are indeed part of the file, containing just a lot of zero bytes - These are just not written on disk.

On some systems, the `lseek` system call may support seek modes named `SEEK_HOLE` and `SEEK_DATA`. This is a nonstandard extension that is present in some versions of Linux, BSD, and Solaris.

These position the file pointer to the next hole when it is currently in allocated space (for `SEEK_HOLE`) or the next "real" data position when in a hole (for `SEEK_DATA`).

Other systems might support an `ioctl` named `FIEMAP` to map logical to physical file positions (which also allows you to detect non-allocated storage).

Comment: thanks for answering, i'm doing an exercises on copying a hole file. I think i can use SEEK_HOLE and SEEK_DATA to get the range of real data in file, and write to new file.